# complex jpql query to build List<> object filtering with nested joins

Tags: java, jpql, criteria-api

I need to build a `Menu/Operation` data structure based on the roles assigned to a given user and I'm not finding the right query in my app. Let's see the details:

### Tables

I'm working in `MySQL`, but that's not the problem, could be any `DBMS`. These are the involved tables in my query

```
CREATE TABLE MENU (
    id_menu tinyint(3)  unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name    varchar(50)          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_menu)
);

CREATE TABLE OPERATION (
    id_operation smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_menu      tinyint(3)  unsigned NOT NULL,
    name         varchar(50)          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_operation),
    CONSTRAINT fk_menu_operation FOREIGN KEY (id_menu) REFERENCES MENU (id_menu)
);

CREATE TABLE ROLE (
    role char(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (role)
);

CREATE TABLE roles_operation (
    id_operation smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    role         char(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_operation, role),
    CONSTRAINT fk_rolop_operation FOREIGN KEY (id_operation) REFERENCES OPERACION (id_operacion),
    CONSTRAINT fk_rolop_role FOREIGN KEY (role) REFERENCES ROL (role)
);
```

The `ROLE` table seems to be useless but I use it to model the relationship with other tables like `USER`, but that's not the problem.

### Mapped `@Entity` classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MENU")
public class Menu implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2884031708620020329L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_menu")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idMenu;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "menu")
    private List<Operation> operations;

    // gettters/setters, toString and other methods...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "OPERATION")
public class Operation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -76328025481684179L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_operation")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idOperation;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_menu")
    @NotNull
    private Menu menu;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "roles_operation",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id_operation", referencedColumnName = "id_operation")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "role", referencedColumnName = "role")})
    private List<Role> allowedRoles;

    // gettters/setters, toString and other methods...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -412065042708649504L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RolEnum role; // Fixed values defined in the same class

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users;  // The roles asigned to the user, doesn't matter here

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "allowedRoles")
    private List<Operation> operations;

    // gettters/setters, toString and other methods...
}
```

My business logic is that *"A User has one or more roles, and a role is given to one or more users"* (a simple `@ManyToMany` relationship). Now, given a user, I need to query, preferably using `JPQL`, to get a `List<Menu>` with the operations assigned to the given `User` via it's roles. With `SQL` I can perform the following query and get the result that I want:

```
select  m.name, o.name, r.role
from    MENU            m   inner join 
        OPERATION       o   on m.id_menu = o.id_menu inner join
        roles_operation ro  on o.id_operation = ro.id_operation inner join
        ROLE            r   on ro.role = r.role
where   r.rol in ('RoleA', 'RoleB') -- User's roles
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to translate this to the `JPQL` language. E.g., if I have the following structure:

#### Example Menu/Operation/Role structure

```
- Menu1
    - Operation1.1
        - RoleA
    - Operation1.2
        -RoleA
        -RoleB 
    - Operation1.3
        -RoleC
- Menu2
    - Operation2.1
        - RoleA 
    - Operation2.2
        - RoleD
    - Operation2.3
        - RoleB
```

And the user has `RoleA` and `RoleB`, I must get the following result (I use a JSON-like format, but these are Java objects)

```
{
     Menu{name=Menu1, 
         operations=[Operation{name=Operation1.1, role=[RoleA]}, 
                     Operation{name=Operation1.2, role=[RoleA, RoleB]}
         ]
    },
    Menu{name=Menu2, 
         operations=[Operation{name=Operation2.1, role=[RoleA]}, 
                     Operation{name=Operation2.3, role=[RoleB]}
         ]
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me writing this query? I've tried this using `JPQL`

```
public List<Menu> buildUserMenu(User user) {
    // Extracts roles from user
    List<Role.RolEnum> roles = user.getRoles().stream()
            .map(rol -> rol.getRol())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT m FROM "
            + "Menu m INNER JOIN "
            + "m.operations o INNER JOIN "
            + "o.allowedRoles r "
            + "WHERE r.role in :roles")
            .setParameter("roles", roles);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

But I'm getting the full structure (like the example structure above). What should be the query in JPQL to build the `List<Menu>` object that I need?

### Note:

If someone has other solution, like using the Criteria API, please tell me how to do it. To be honest, I don't know quite well how to use that API.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

---

## The failing test

#### Test class

```
public class MenuOperationRepositoryTest extends BaseTestRepository {

    // The class to test
    private MenuOperationRepository menuOperationRepository;

    @Before
    public void initTestCase() {
        // Build EntityManager and some other utility classes,
        // load some static data in the test DB (trust me, this works fine)
        initTestDB(); // this method is part of BaseTestRepository class

        // manual dependency injection (also working correctly)
        menuOperationRepository = new MenuOperationRepository();
        menuOperationRepository.entityManager = em;
        menuOperationRepository.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MenuOperationRepository.class);

        // Add some data to DB specific for this class
        // The parameters are static methods that returns dummy data
        addMenuOperations(menu1(), operation11RoleA(), operation12RoleB(), operation13RoleC());
        addMenuOperations(menu2(), operation21RoleB(), operation22RoleA(), operation());
    }

    @After
    public void finishTestCase() {
        // Closes em and emf (EntityManagerFactory)
        closeEntityManager();
    }

    @Test
    public void buildMenuWithOperationsFilteredByRoles() {
        // userWithId() generates a dummy User object with Id as if saved in the DB
        // userRoleARoleB() generates a dummy object like menu1() and has RoleA and RoleB
        List<Menu> result = menuOperationRepository.buildUserMenu(userWithId(userRoleARoleB(), 1L));

        // the assertion methods are statically imported from org.junit.Assert and org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers

        // I should be getting menu1() and menu2()
        assertThat(result.size(), is(equalTo(2)));
        // menu1() should contain operation11RoleA() and operation12RoleB()
        assertThat(result.get(0).getOperations().size(), is(equalTo(2)));
        // menu2() should contain operation21RoleB() and operation22RoleA()
        assertThat(result.get(1).getOperations().size(), is(equalTo(2)));
    }

    /*
     *   HELPER METHODS
     */
    private void addMenuOperations(Menu menu, Operation... operations) {
        List<Operacion> operationList = Arrays.asList(operations);

        // This is a utility class which manages the connections manually
        // I use this in my tests only, in the server this is done automatically
        // This works correctly
        dbCommandExecutor.executeCommand(() -> {
            em.persist(menu);
            operationList.forEach((op) -> {
                op.setMenu(menu);
                em.persist(op);
            });
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

#### The class to test

```
public class RepositorioMenuOperacion {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "sigeaPU")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    public List<Menu> buildUserMenu(User user) {
        logger.debug("buildUserMenu({})", user);

        // Extracts roles from user object, this works fine according to the log trace
        List<Rol.RolEnum> roles = usuario.getRoles().stream()
                .map(rol -> rol.getRol())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        logger.debug("Extracted roles: {}", roles);

        // The query I'm using and that I posted previously
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT m FROM "
                + "Menu m INNER JOIN "
                + "m.operations o INNER JOIN "
                + "o.allowedRoles r "
                + "WHERE r.role in :roles")
                .setParameter("roles", roles);

        List<Menu> menuList = query.getResultList();
        logger.info("Menu List found");
        menuList.forEach(menu -> logger.info(menu.toString()));

        return menuList;
    }
}
```

I think this gives a full picture of the problem. I need to rewrite the query or to filter the `menuList` after the query but I can't solve it. I give it a try with filtering after querying but I'm getting a `ConcurrentModificationException`, can't say exactly why.

If you need more data about my application, just let me know.

Comment: If you are comfortable with native queries then use `EntityManager.createNativeQuery`

Comment: That's the point, I don't feel comfortable with native queries, what if I want to migrate to another Database in the future (e.g. postgres)? I don't want to couple the business logic (written in Java) with the data layer logic (MySQL for now). Moreover, until now I've been working quite well retrieving data with `JPQL` and managing the logic with Java, but I'm stuck with this point. This is the most complex query I'm expecting to have in my application... Besides, it's a good chance to learn a little bit more about `JPA`, don't you think?

Comment: If your DB is setup correctly (FK etc) and you are using Eclipse, it is a simple matter to generate DAO and Entities for your DB.  All joins will by default be available via lazy loads

Comment: @ScaryWombat My entity classes are correct (it's tested) and I don't need to generate DAO, my problem is to filter (the `WHERE` clause, I presume) the result list I'm getting from the query execution. I'll add my failing test so you can get a full picture of the problem

Comment: @ScaryWombat, check the added section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine, but it doesn't return what you want. It returns all the menus containing at least one allowed operation. And since it returns Menus, and menus have operations, the returned menus contain all their operations. Because that's what a association is: it doesn't contain entries specific to a given query. It contains the operations of the menu.

What you need, instead of returning the menus, is to return the allowed operations. You can then get their menu using the ManyToOne association:

```
select o from Operation o
join o.allowedRoles role
where role role in :roles
```

That will only return the operations allowed to the user.

Comment: Ok, that's something, thank you. One more thing: Once I get the `List<Operation>` Collection, how should I transform it to a `List<Menu>`? Maybe you've already thought on this an have in mind a simple and elegant way to do it.

Comment: `operations.stream().map(Operation::getMenu).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Sorry, we're missing something. Apparently, when invoking `operations.stream()..` creates another query and returns me the menus with all it's operations like my original query.

Comment: Yes, obviously. As I explained in my answer, the collection of operations of a menu will always contain all the operations of the menu. Never something specific to a query. That's what an association is. And that's precisely why you shouldn't get the operations from there. You should get them from the list of operations returned by the query. Those are the operations that are allowed to the user. And those operations belong to menus which contain other operations.

Comment: I'm now querying as you said in your answer, but when I execute `operations.stream().map(Operation::getMenu).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())` Hibernate creates another query and does something similar to the original query in my method, so my test is failing because again I'm getting menus with all the operations. How can I execute the convertion from `List<Operation>` to `List<Menu>` without querying again through the `@ManyToOne` relationship?

Comment: Getting the menus from the operations is not what loads the operations of the menus, unless the association is eager, or you access the operations from your Menu.equals() method. The operations of the menus are most probably loaded because your test prints the menus, and Menu.toString() method prints the operations. Which, of course, requires the operations of the menus to be loaded. But you seem, once again, surprised to have all the operations in the menu. That will ALWAYS happen. You will NEVER have a subset of the menu operations by getting the operations from the menus.

Comment: The operations that the user is allowed to access are the ones returned by the query. Not the ones in the menus of the operations returned by the query. Just like if I ask "what are the male children of your family?", you'll say "John and Jack". Then I'll ask John and Jack "who is your dad?, and they'll answer "Mike". Then I'll ask Mike "who are your children?", and Mike will say "John, Jack, Mary and Laura". See, the children of Mike are the children of Mike, all of them, whether you started by querying for the male children or not.

Comment: After some deep research on Hibernate, I gave up on filtering and mapping, because when you execute `operations.stream()...` Hibernates automatically queries, using your analogy, *on Mike's children* and not only *on Mike's male children*. The solution was to retrieve the data with your query and work with that. I can't map as you said in your comment because every `get()` on an `@Entity` class in a `@PersistenceContext` triggers a query if the data is not there. Good concept to have in mind